# How to edit one attribute in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-collections-api

I have 4 classes.
Program
Customer
Part
Task

I have an ArrayList where i save data (int procent, Customer k, Task u , boolean f)

I assign values to everything with a scanner and then partList.add(). And everything works great.

Now i want to change only the last boolean value from false to true.

```
Code: 
// ArrayList in class Customer
private ArrayList<Part> partList = new ArrayList<Part> (); 

// Constructor in class Part
public Part(int procent, Customer k, Task u,boolean f) {
```

In the class Customer i want to change the boolean value (Part) in my ArrayList for a specific object (Customer). Possible solutions?

Comment: please edit your question, it's not clear enough

Comment: yes, it is possible, I suggest you try. Which version of Java are you using?

Answer (score -1):

In Java 7 you would do

```
for (Part part : partList)
    if (part.k == customer)
        part.f = true;
```

or in Java 8 you can do

```
partList.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.k == customer)
        .forEach(p -> p.f = true);
```

Comment: I get that searching trought the list with a for loop is good. But i get error "f and k cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Comment: @Maybex You called the `k` and `f` in your question.  I assume you know what you called your fields in `Part` or you could include them in the question if you can't do the substitution.

Comment: Why would you do that? If you already have `customer` you would just do `customer.f = true;`. No need to search at all.